# freelance web sites: is personal opinion a good idea?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed that there's a lot of questions that include names of freelance sites.  To my disappointment it's not many web sites.  My question is: whether positive or negative opinions, what does SE think of expressing opinions of freelance web sites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of evaluating actual freelance websites, where the results are opinions and also information that may quickly become outdated, it's best to instead ask how to evaluate a freelance website.  This information would be useful for years to come, and it would teach not just tell.

If we teach people what to look for in a good freelance website, then they'll be empowered to do their own research, no matter how many of these sites come and go in and out of business.

Answer (score 4):

I think that we should disallow recommendations of what site(s) to use, as it is easy to just answer with a list. That also makes the site quality go down as time goes on, unless the list stays updated, does not include spam, and is referred to often, instead of multiple questions asking the same thing.

If that's not what you're asking, then please edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: I thought of a few negative things about a couple of freelance sites.  I'm afraid to voice my opinion.  On the one hand they might improve.  On the other I don't have a strong client base and it could hurt me instead.  But your answer did the trick.  Also, the amount of time the question's been out there with only one response also speaks to me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the mention of **any** website should be needed. A question should be asked, and answered, without **ever** needing to mention **any** of these web sites.

If the question *can't* be asked or answered unless you mention the site, then I feel the question is off topic per the "not a support site for (website)" guideline.

The truth of the matter is, like all services, you'll find some users like it, some don't. I don't think it should be the goal of this stack to neither support nor detract from any other site specifically.